# How to list a reference contact that left the company we worked together at and where the company changed its name

Tags: applications, references

One of the persons I want to give as reference contact for my applications has left the company where we worked together *and* the company has changed its name since then. Since I still worked there after the rebranding, I will give only the new name in my resume (the rebranding is shortly explained in the letter of reference I have from that company).

Normally I would list my contacts as "name, position, company, contact information", and I could handle one of the two conditions above with sufficient clarity – for example by writing "*Company* (now at *Other Company*)" for the former case or "*Company* (former *Old Company Name*)" for the latter. However, I feel I cannot give both bits of information precisely without creating a lot of "former's" and "now's" and nonetheless t would be not sufficiently clear who was where and when.

Any ideas how I could communicate this in a short fashion without having to write a half novel about it or, if not possible, which of the two facts is less critical to omit?

Comment: @Lilienthal Well, here in the German speaking countries employers are obliged by law to hand out an employee that is leaving the company a so called "Arbeitszeugnis" which basically describes what (s)he has done there and how satisfied the employer was with their work (for a more elaborate explanation see [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36458/42900)). You add those documents to your application so the recruiting firms can get a good first overview about what you have done and how good you are. Hence there's no need for every hiring company to automatically call a ...

Comment: ...reference contact. Instead, it's a nice-to-have add-on that might give you the decisive step ahead of the other applicants if things get close. Many employers even don't contact the references at all, but take already the fact, that you are willing and able to name references as a sign of "This applicant has nothing to hide". So it is not expected that a reference contact is called from every potential employer I apply at, but only in cases where they need the last bit of additional information to make a decision between two evenly qualified candidates.